# ASP.NET Identity 2 execute code after cookie authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm using ASP.NET Identity 2 authentication via OWIN middlewear.  I've created a new project using the template so initially started with the default generated code but have changed it a bit (taken out entity framework and wired in my own existing authentication).  This is all working.

What I'd now like to do is execute code after a user logs in via a saved cookie.  I've had a look at ConfigureAuth in the Startup.Auth.cs file which I've configured as follows:

```
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app) {

        // Configure the user manager and signin manager to use a single instance
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider {                    
                OnResponseSignIn = ctx => {
                    Log.Trace("On Response Sign In.");
                },
                OnResponseSignedIn = ctx => {
                    Log.Trace("On Response Signed In.");
                },
                OnValidateIdentity = async ctx => {
                    Log.Trace("On Validate Identity.");
                }
            }
        });            

    }
```

From this I can see that OnResponseSignIn and OnResponseSignedIn are hit only during actual logins when the user enters their username and password.  They are not hit when the user is authenticated via saved cookie.

OnValidateIdentity is hit regardless of whether the user authenticated via username/password or saved cookie and it's hit for every request they make.

What I'd like is to execute code just once after a login via cookie.  Does anyone know how to do this?  If not, I guess another option is to put code in OnValidateIdentity but in an if statement that will prevent it being run unless its the first call after the cookie authentication.  Can anyone think of how to achieve that?  All I can think of is to set a variable in Session after the code is first run and check for it's presence to prevent it being re-run?

Comment: Problem with your task is "execute code just once after a login via cookie". What is "login via cookie"? I suspect you'd like to know if users have a persistent cookie and came back to your site after some inactivity. But what is "inactivity"? is 5 minutes enough to qualify for inactivity? What about 24 hours? 48 hours? Once you define this, I'll probably be able to tell you where to look at.

Comment: @trailmax thanks and apologies for the delay.  Yes you hit the nail on the head: it's if they have a persistent cookie.  Basically, if they come to the site without a cookie, they enter their username and password and I can hook into that process.  The problem is when they come back with a persistent cookie.  Essentially I want the code to run whenever they come back and start a new session, regardless of how long it's been.  I.e. if they come back, supply the cookie and the application lets them in, having sidestepped entering a username and password, I want some code to run.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Kiquenet sorry, I don't think I did.

Answer (score 0):

It can probably be done by using a session variable as a flag, and only do your thing when it is not set.

```
OnValidateIdentity = async context => {
    if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Refreshed"] == null)
    {
        /** do your thing **/
        ...

        HttpContext.Current.Session["Refreshed"] = new object();
    }
}
```